# Connecting oci8 to Apache & PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache2

We're building a Debian server to host a website which is built on PHP. It connects to an Oracle database. I need to connect the PHP to the Oracle database using oci8. However, some of the steps I've seen online require the use of oracle-xe-client package. I cannot find this package at the moment. Any help or advice about the process is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [these directions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php)? Because they don't mention oracle-xe-client. Otherwise that package can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/102xelinsoft-102048.html).

Otherwise, both PDO and ODBC have drivers for Oracle, albeit the ones for PDO are experimental.

Comment: Thank you. It does mention the Oracle client in the instructions. However, I really appreciate your help!